# What am I doing wrong with this simple integration problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

Basically, I'm supposed to find the distance $s$ as a function of time $t$ given that velocity $v=v_0e^{-ct}$, where $v_0$ is the initial velocity. I know I have to integrate both sides with respect to $t$, since $v=ds/dt$, and when I do that I get $$s=v_0\int{e^{-ct}}dt=v_0(C-\frac{1}{c}e^{-ct})$$.
The problem is, according to my book, the answer should be $$s=\frac{v_0}{c}(1-e^{-ct})$$
and I'm not sure these are equivalent expressions. I don't think $\frac{v_0}{c}=v_0C$, since $C$ and $c$ may assume different values from one another. So what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct. Just find $C$ such that the initial condition is satisfied: $s(0)=0$, that is the the distance at time $0$  is $0$.

Comment: You did not enforce an initial condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $t=0$ we must have $s(t)=s(0)=0$. Therefore the integration constant is not arbitary and the solution in the book is correct.

But you were on the right track. Without an initial condition, your solution is correct. Using $s(0)=0$ finishes the calculation leading to the book-answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$ds=v_0e^{-ct}dt$$ and by definite integration form $0$ to $t$,

$$s-s_0=v_0\frac{1-e^{-ct}}c.$$

---

The problem statement does not specify $s_0$ but it is natural to assume $0$.